# Should the [registration] and [sign-up] tags be merged, and if so, what should be the canonical tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, meta, retag-request

Here on this site, we have two tags [registration](/questions/tagged/registration) and [sign-up](/questions/tagged/sign-up), which mean essentially the same thing: registering (signing up) for an account on any site on the network.

Looking at the uses for each tag, most of them seem to be about the same use above. The use of each tag depends on which wording the author of the question used (was thinking of at the time they wrote the question). The only slight difference I can see is some questions using the [registration](/questions/tagged/registration) tag asking not about how to sign up for the site, but about converting an unregistered account into a registered account, but the process is still the same (you do so by signing up for the site using email/password or a login provider, as stated in the [sign-up](/questions/tagged/sign-up) tag's description).

Should these tags be merged? If so, which tag should remain (I think [sign-up](/questions/tagged/sign-up) because it has more questions and a tag description)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm very much in favor of merging the two, and keeping [sign-up](/questions/tagged/sign-up) as the main tag.

I'll add another argument to your existing argument of most questions, and a tag description:

[image: Screenshot of Meta Stack Exchange when not logged in. Freehand red circles drawn around the "sign up" button in the top left corner next to the "sign in" button and around the wording "Sign up" in the sentence "Sign up to join this community" in the banner on top of the page.]

The official verbiage used on the website itself is also "Sign up", as you can see in the screenshot above.